# How to write unit test cases for session variables in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

Hello I have a test case which will call a route and it will return some data if the session will set.
Here is my test case

```
class TestControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    // ...

    public function testResponseOfJson()
    {
        $response = $this->call('GET', 'profile/test');
        $this->assertEmpty( !$response );
    }

    // ...
}
```

and here is my controller

```
Class TestController{
   public function sendResponse(Request $request){
     $this->data['user_id'] = $this->request->session()->get('userdata.userid'); 
if($this->data['userid']){
   return data;
}
else{ 
   return Failed;
     }
   }
}
```

My routes.php

```
Route::get('profile/test',['uses'=>'TestController@sendResponse']);
```

how can i set the session variable userdata.userid and get while doing unit testing.

Comment: You have 17 questions, and one accepted answer. It's never too late to fix that...

Answer (score 2):

Please check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests) page.

Laravel gives you the capability of using `withSession` chain method and other functions that will help you test where a session is required or needs to be manipulated in some way.

Example:

```
<?php

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testApplication()
    {
        $response = $this->withSession(['foo' => 'bar'])
                         ->get('/');
    }
}
```